# Anti-aero resistance training jerseys?

Tags: training, clothes, aerodynamics

Is there any manufacturer that makes specific anti-aero training jerseys for increased effort at lower speeds? Sort of like a braking parachute but more practical and subtle?

My reason for asking is that I want my fairly short commutes to give better training while not requiring unsafe speeds in city riding.

Edit: and just to explain.. I'm not so keen on adding weight to my bike or person - not only because it is unpractical, but also because it would make the effort more uneven and more like interval training rather than sustained effort.

Comment: You might consider simply carrying rear panniers.  Front panniers can actually improve aero flow, but rear panniers are usually a drag.  Or use cardboard boxes instead of panniers, to be able to control the cross-section.

Comment: A little bit on the pricey side, but there are [hubs](http://www.wired.com/2011/09/1200-powerwheels-sole-function-is-to-slow-down-your-bike/) designed to specifically slow down your bike.  Would be an interesting tool if it wasn't so ridiculously expensive. Looks like their official website is now [parked](http://trisportdevices.com/), which means you probably can't get them.

Comment: I've put some ideas in an answer but bnote that it would be good if you gave us an idea of typical speeds and for how long.  Drag won't do much until you're up to a decent speed.  Also how much power do you average, and how much harder would you like it to be?

Comment: You could also use too high a gear for the speed you're going to gain more resistance (but low enough so that your cadence is still OK).

Comment: I prefer to run fat tyres at low pressure. If you can get Marathon Plus tyres for your bike they're even better, because the anti-puncture blob is worse. I used to ride a popular route with a few others who rode mountain bikes with fat tyres for the same reasons. If you have budget, buy a 4" tyre monster :)

Comment: How about towing a trailer?  Or bike further - pick a route that goes the scenic route.   Draw a picture on strava over time!

Comment: Some more cheap ideas to slow you down: raise your handlebars, spin lower gears at higher cadence, and put that anti-puncture slime stuff in your tubes.  For more money, get a nice heavy wheelset with 36 spokes and a hub dynamo with nice bright power-hungry lights.

Comment: You could consider repacking the bearings in your hubs and bottom bracket with tar. :)

Comment: @JohnZwinck - The weight of the wheels will make very little difference.  The dynamo, however, can add a modest amount of resistance.

Comment: @DanielRHicks: the weight of the wheels may make only a small difference, but I did specify 36 spokes in an effort to screw up the aero.  I suppose one could also install bladed spokes crosswise to further sabotage efficiency.

Comment: @JohnZwinck - I'm skeptical as to how much extra spokes will "screw up" aerodynamics in the absence of aero rims, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @DanielRHicks says, a large pannier will do this (searching for "large triple rear pannier" gives a few hits for <£20 (probably ~$20).  You could make these work with a seatpost-mounted rack if you filled them with polystyrene.  A handlebar bag might "help" as well.  Ordinary clothes (loose fitting) will do more than anything that looks like a jersey/tights.

Also consider higher-rolling resistance tyres (they might save wear on your expensive races tyres and reduce the chance of punctures as well).  At race speed air drag dominates but at commuting speeds rolling resistance might well add something useful.  It's a pity hub dynamos don't come in higher powers or easily fit back wheels -- [apparently the Shimano DH3D71 will supply 10W at 40km/h into a dummy load](http://www.pilom.com/BicycleElectronics/HubDynamo.htm), which is starting to get interesting but doesn't really get there.  It might be interesting to run the numbers on how much you could make a front wheel drag with anything-but-aero rims, a dynamo and inefficient tyres (I'm thinking touring tyres slightly wider than you've got with a lower pressure).  You'd need to put your commuting speed/power profile  into the calculations to see how it would work out.  Just say you were burning 200W and doing 40km/h though, the dynamo alone would add ~5%.

Comment: I would guess you'd need a dynamo (and matching "load") of 50 watts or more to be worthwhile as a training aid.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I was thinking of about half that -- a 10% increment in resistance is a reasonable step size -- which is why I wished for more. But I wonder what you could add up to with all my wheel-based suggestions (especially given how small an improvement people claim to feel).

Answer (score 3):

Since drag is related to velocity squared at low speeds anti-aero won't do much.  Bulky regular clothes but that won't change your aerodynamics much. Why not just divert and take a longer route to commute?